# Removing functions from Javascript files using SED

Tags: bash, sed

How can I delete, or clear out the unknown contents of a specific function using Bash/SED from a javascript file? For example, my .js file I want to empty func1 and func3 from the following:

```
function func1(){
    //unknown contents
}
function func2(){
    //unknown contents
}
function func3() {
    func1();
    if (var1) {
        func2();
    } else {
        func4();
    }
}
```

I want it to look like this

```
function func1(){
}
function func2(){
    //do something
}
function func3() {
}
```

if it were HTML blocks it would be easier as each closing tag is unique

Something along the lines of this:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/function func1(){.*}/function func1(){newcode.*}/g' file.js
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is `sed` the tool that you require for this task?

Comment: It is what I've been mostly using for other projects, open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk '/^}/{flag=""} /function func1/||/function func3/{flag=1;print;next} flag{next} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
function func1(){
}
function func2(){
    //unknown contents
}
function func3() {
}
```

Comment: That works great thanks. How would I replace the function content with new text?
Also, is there an easy way to do in-place editing? It seems you can do it in gawk.

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed '/function func1\|function func3/!b;:A;N;;/\n}/!{s/\n.*//;bA}' file.js
```

sed -i to replace.